Plotting SHmax data from World Stress Map
I have a .dat data of SHmax orientation from WSM database, but I want to plot it by myself without using CASMO app. Can you help me to plot it ? Here is a example of that datasets (in .dat extension):
LON LAT SHmax   N   sd  radius  Plate
-180.0  -67.0   69.37   7   24.15   400 AN
-180.0  -66.8   69.59   7   24.15   400 AN
-180.0  -66.6   69.81   7   24.13   400 AN
-180.0  -66.4   69.99   7   24.09   400 AN
-180.0  -66.2   67.46   8   24.95   450 AN
-180.0  -66.0   67.64   8   24.79   500 AN
The procedure or example of plotting code in Mercator orientation.
